# Are Compendium Classes from pre-release still valid?

Tags: dungeon-world

I have several Dungeon World compendium classes for the Red Book era and I wonder if they still work / are intended to be used with the game as released. Examples off the top of my head include:

- The Villager
- The Walking Dead
- The Epicurian (? It was a class that appreciated the finer things in life)

Most of these were from the Adventurer's Guild if my memory is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Someone asked about the Villager on [The Dungeon World Tavern](https://plus.google.com/109563461718222144273/posts/Yy2skrzhFvE) recently. The given answers suggested it was fine, and having looked at my copy, I'd agree.

No idea on the others. They're not in the kickstarter backers' compendium class collection.